# Jquery : Need to check a list of values in a combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am totally confused how to make it.. Here is my problem.

I have n number of customized combo boxes (Which creates dynamically from the server side). Now i want to store the values of each combo box and need to validate by client side. If any one of the combo box val() == 0(i mean no option selected), then i need to show an error message. If all the combo box values are selected, then i need to show a a div in a popup. All these actions have to be happened if i click the save button.

Since these combo boxes are rendering dynamically, i cannot use its ID. My idea is to give a class name called combo and need to validate. Here is my code,

#### HTML (dynamicaaly generated)

```
 <select class="combo">
     <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
     <option value="1">Employee First Name (HR)</option>
     <option value="2">Employee last Name (HR)</option>
     <option value="3">Employee number (HR)</option>
      <option value="4">NINO (HR)</option>
 </select>
```

#### jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

$('#save').click(function(){


    var myLength = $('.combo option:selected').length;


    alert(myLength);
    if(myLength > 0){
        alert('popups here');
        count=count+1;
        alert(count);
         var maskHeight = $(document).height();
         var maskWidth = $(window).width();
         $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
         $('#mask').fadeTo("fast",0.8); 
         var winH = $(window).height();
         var winW = $(window).width();
         $('.popups').css('top',winH/2-$('.popups').height()/2);
         $('.popups').css('left',winW/2-$('.popups').width()/2);
         $('.popups').show(); 
         } 
         else 
         {
         alert('No popups');
         }
         return false;
});

 });
```

The idea is not working. Please suggest how to proceed... Many thanks :)

Comment: will You please show the Dynamically generated html too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var trace = false;
$('#save').on('click', function() {
    $('select.combo').each(function() {
        if(this.value == 0){
            trace = true;
            return;
        }           
    });
    if(trace) {
        // all combo not selected
        alert('Please select all combo');
        trace = false;
    } else {
        // all selected
        alert('Thanks..');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

#### HTML

```
<select class="combo" multiple="multiple">
 <option selected="selected" value="0" >--SELECT ONE--</option>
 <option value="1">Employee First Name (HR)</option>
 <option value="2">Employee last Name (HR)</option>
 <option value="3">Employee number (HR)</option>
 <option value="4">NINO (HR)</option>
```

​

#### jQuery

```
var foo = {};

$('#submit').live('click', function() {
    $('select.combo').each(function(i) {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        foo[i] = selected;
    });

    //this will remove first value ( blank having value=0)
    var finalOutput = jQuery.grep(foo[0], function(value) {
        //this will unselect the blank value
        $('.combo option:eq(0)').prop('selected', false);
        return value != "0";
    });

    if ($.isEmptyObject(finalOutput)) {
        alert('please select atlest one')
    }
    else {
        alert('Output:' + finalOutput)
    }
})​​
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/SmKU6/1)

Comment: checkbox != combobox (combobox == select)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But iam using a customized combo box,

<select class="combo">
                      
<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
<option value="1">Employee First Name (HR)</option>                   
<option value="2">Employee last Name (HR)</option>
<option value="3">Employee number (HR)</option>
<option value="4">NINO (HR)</option>   
</select>

Suggest me how to proceed. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Riyas how can you select more than one option in combo box?? is it multiple selectbox

Comment: I have updated the code meanwhile you changed the question again.

Comment: Yes. this is a selectbox, but iam having 10 dynamic selectbox now. Now i need to validate 10 number of selectboxes selected value ==0. If any one of the selectbox value is 0, then i should get an alert message. Else, i should be doing something.

Comment: this `map() `function does for all option box together

Comment: @diecho: the updated code works fine with one selectbox. But i need to validate this for 10 selectboxes. Sorry for the mess...

Comment: @Riyas I have updated again. this will also take care if you select Blank one together with other options

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
   var comboLength = $('.combo').length;
   var selectedLength = $('.combo option:selected[value!=0]').length;

   if (comboLength == selectedLength) { /* code for valid case*/}
   else { /*code for invalid case*/; return false;}
})
```

Comment: Var comboLength and selectedLength are getting same values here. So the value is not passing to the else condition.

Comment: Well, if the selectedLength equals the comboLentgh, but not all the comboboxes have selections, then the selector is wrong ($('.combo option:selected'))

Comment: Does each combo has a default value?

Comment: Yes. default selected value is 0.

Comment: Try this selector : $('.combo option:selected[value!=0]').length . I'm updating my answer